# One way communication over TCP Socket

Tags: python, c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send some data  to a remote Raspberry Pi over TCP socket from a GUI that I designed with Python. I've implemented some basic codes. The problem is it does not give any error on Python side and Raspberry Pi side but somehow data never reaches on Raspberry Pi side.

Here is part of my Python code which is working on the PC.

```
    self.sendsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sendsocket.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    self.sendsocket.send("Hello world!")
    self.sendsocket.close()
```

and this is C code working on Raspberry Pi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
    {
    int sockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    portno = 5005;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
         sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd,5);
    bzero(buffer,1024);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,1024);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are reading from `newsockfd`, which doesn't seem to declared or initialized anywhere. Are you missing your `accept` call?

Comment: The posted code could be a [MCVE] with little effort

Comment: Copy/paste only code that you have tested, else you will end up wasting everyone's time with omissions and typos:(

Comment: @venth1a, please do not edit the question to incorporate the solution because it is difficult for future readers to follow. I have rolled it back for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Ras-pi side, you are reading from `newsockfd` but you are neither declaring it nor, initializing it. Also, you are just `listen`-ing to the socket, but never [`accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)-ing a connection.

You need to add this -

```
socklen_t length = 0;
int newsockfd = accept(socket, NULL, &length);
```

before your call to `read`.

Also, as mentioned by `@sjsam` in the comments, you need to close the socket after you are done reading using -

```
close(newsockfd);
close(socket);
```

It would also be good to refactor the code and move the connection handling to a separate function (or a thread), so that your server can accept more connection. But if this is just a MCVE, that is alright.

Comment: Good point. The op might need a handler function too for each client socket it receives thru `accept(socket, NULL, &length);` and the `handler` after doing the necessary operations should take care of closing the socket by a call to `close(socketfd)`. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable  `newsockfd` (and declare it ? ) before `read` and you need a variable of type `socklen_t`

something like :

`socklen_t addr_size = sizeof cli_addr;
 newsockfd = accept(sockfd,&cli_addr,&addr_size);`

and just then use the read function.